# How many different ways are there to put $9$ coins in $9$ boxes if...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

the coins are all identical and exactly six boxes are empty.

My first thought was that it should be ${9\choose6} {{3+9-1}\choose9} $, first choosing the $6$ empty boxes and then distributing the identical coins to the remaining $3$ boxes.

However, the answer is in fact ${9\choose6} {{8}\choose6} $. I think the ${9\choose6}$ is the number of ways of selecting the empty boxes, but what is  ${{8}\choose6} $?

Where am I going wrong in my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First choose the $6$ empty boxes in $\binom{9}{6}$ ways then put one coin in each of the $3$ boxes which are supposed to be filled (this way you have ensured that these $3$ boxes will not be empty). Now you have to distribute $6$ coins in these $3$ boxes which can be done in $\binom{8}{6}$ ways.

In your method you are not guaranteeing that the remaining $3$ boxes have to be filled.

Comment: yes, completely right. I thought of it just after I posted the question actually :)

Answer (score 0):

The second term ${{3+9-1} \choose 9}$ in your product is the number of ways to distribute 9 items into 3 boxes, but in this setting it is possible for some of the boxes to be empty.  To guarantee that the three boxes are nonempty, you put one item into each of the three boxes, and the question is really how to distribute the remaining 6 items into the three boxes, and now, the boxes are allowed to be empty,  so you can use your approach to obtain the second term to be ${{3+6-1} \choose 6}$.